# Why is step response of an opamp linear/exponential?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, inverting-amplifier, step-response, slew-rate

My step response for LM741 at LTSpice was this:
[image]

And for TL081:
[image]

So as you can see the response of LM741 is linear and of TL081 is exponential, but why? My schematic is an inverting amplifier with v=10.

Answer (score 3):

The LM741 has a slew rate of only 0.5V per us. The TL081 has 20V per us. So the LM741 ist just damn slow :-)

Answer (score 2):

The LM741 is being slew-rate limited here; op amps have a maximum slew rate, which is the maximum slope at which the output can change. The LM741 has a particularly low one (it's about the worst op amp on the market, and really shouldn't be used for anything. I don't know why it's still manufactured.).

The TL081 is faster, but approaches its final value exponentially likely because your feedback network is slowing it down somewhat; it'd help if we could see the circuit including the actual resistances used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Both opamps outputs are limited by slew rate here. My circuit is a normal inverting amplifier with a 1kΩ and a 10 kΩ resistor. If my feedback network would slow it down, than both circuits would get affected and not just the one with TL081.

Comment: @MS You're right, with 1k and 10k resistors you're not going to see anything slowed down by this much. I'm too exhausted from a long week at work to do any detailed analysis here, though. My answer might just be wrong. Though I will reiterate that the LM741 is *very* obsolete and should never be used. *Please* don't keep using the LM741. The TL081 is also pretty antiquated, but it at least has some half decent specs.

Comment: I think slew rate is indeed the correct mechanism here. SPICE opamp subcircuits usually model this effect with a current source charging a capacitor. When the current source hits the limit it becomes constant and therefore the capacitor voltage rises/falls in a linear ramp. This is exactly what is shown in the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Real world op-amps have limitations of the real world.

One such limitation is bandwidth. They do not have infinite bandwidth and it means for a relatively fast step input which has relatively high bandwidth, the op-amp output will not be a step but something limited by the bandwidth.

Different op-amps have different circuitry and different bandwidth.

Also the simulation model for the op-amps may be true or approximate or arbitrary very simple model where bandwidth is simulated just with limited slew rate so the output will be a trapezoid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I actually measured the step response in the real world with an oscilloscope and got a similar result, so the models are pretty accurate. I believe that the bandwidth limitation should not make too much of a difference.

Comment: Don't forget that bandwidth and slew rate are separate limitations, though. They're related, but bandwidth does not determine slew rate directly or vice versa.